# How can I reach my list in a different class from my Program class and then print it out?

Tags: c#, .net, list, oop, console-application

im trying to make a ToDo application in c#. I managed to make so that the user can add a task to the list. However i want to be able to print out the listItems in a foreach loop, but I dont know how to reach it.

This is my Class with my list:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ToDo
{
    public class TodoCollection
    {
        //Declaring my fields
        List<Task> _CurrentTasks = new List<Task>();
        List<Task> _ArchivedTasks = new List<Task>();


        //Method for user to add to the list
        public void Add(Task NewTask)
        {
            _CurrentTasks.Add(NewTask);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Program class where i want to print out all the listItems the user has entered:

```
 while (isRunning)
            {
                var menu = new menu();
                menu.Title();
                menu.Options();
                switch (choices)
                {
                    case 1:
                        var inputNewTask = Console.ReadLine();
                        var task = new Task(inputNewTask, false);
                        collection.Add(task);
                        // Console.WriteLine(task.ShowTask());
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        foreach(Task newTask in  ) 
                        {

                        }
                    break;    
                }
```

As you can see my foreach statement is not done yet. I dont know  what I should put there for it to reach the list and then print it out.

I also have a class of Tasks:

```
namespace ToDo
{
    public class Task
    {
        string _Name;
        bool isDone = false;
        public Task(string name, bool done)
        {
            this._Name = name;
            this.isDone = done;
        }


        public string ShowTask()
        {
            return this._Name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `collection.Add(task);` - where did `collection` come from? :)

Comment: "Collection" is an instance from my class "ToDoCollection".

Comment: ```var collection = new TodoCollection();```

Comment: So you want to be able to do something like `foreach(Task task in collection){ Console.WriteLine(task.ShowTask()); }`?

Comment: yes pretty much, however i cant figure out what to write in the loop. I tried to use ```collection``` but it didnt work

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the loop itself, but `TodoCollection` is not actually a _collection_ (other than by name) - you need to fix that :)

Comment: So by adding this IEnumerable. Did that make my collection to be an actual collection?

Comment: No, we just made it _enumerable_ (or _countable_ if you will) - now anyone can fetch the items from the `_CurrentTasks` lists 1 by 1 via `TodoCollection`. You can implement more advanced collection interfaces (like `ICollection` or `IList`) if you need additional functionality. `IEnumerable` is the "bare minimum" for getting it to work with `foreach`

Answer (score 0):

Your `TodoCollection` class needs to, at the very least, implement the [`IEnumerable` interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable?view=net-6.0) in order for `foreach()` to be able to iterate over it:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ToDo
{
    public class TodoCollection : IEnumerable<Task>
    {
        //Declaring my fields
        List<Task> _CurrentTasks = new List<Task>();
        List<Task> _ArchivedTasks = new List<Task>();


        //Method for user to add to the list
        public void Add(Task NewTask)
        {
            _CurrentTasks.Add(NewTask);
        }

        public IEnumerator<Task> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return ((IEnumerable<Task>)_CurrentTasks).GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return ((IEnumerable)_CurrentTasks).GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can do:

```
foreach(Task task in collection)
{
    Console.WriteLine(task.ShowTask());
}
```

Comment: This did the trick! Thanks alot. i need to read up on IEnumerable. Dont really know what it does. Im very new to c# and .NET

Comment: @MarcusRosberg I strongly recommend reading through the example and remarks in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable). If my answer solves your problem, consider [marking it accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark to the left of it :)